# Named function cases in proof by induction

Tags: isabelle

Is it possible to use names `pred_Zero` and `pred_Suc` instead of `1` and `2` in the following proof by induction?

```
fun pred where
  pred_Zero:
  "pred 0 = 0"
| pred_Suc:
  "pred (Suc n) = n"

lemma pred_le:
  "pred n ≤ n"
proof (induct rule: pred.induct)
  case 1
  thus ?case by simp
next
  case (2 n)
  thus ?case by simp
qed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign names to the cases of an `induction` or `cases` rule using the `case_names` attribute:

```
proof (induct rule: pred.induct [case_names pred_Zero pred_Suc])
```

More canonical names for the cases would be `0` and `Suc`, and in this particular case you might as well just use the default induction rule `nat.induct` anyway since the induction rule generated for`pred` is identical to `nat.induct`.

Comment: Thanks! It's just a simplified example. In general I define a more complicated function with a lot of cases. So proof with 1, 2, 3, ... is unreadable. If I understood you right I should define something like `lemmas pred_induct = pred.induct [case_names 0 Suc]`? It's done automatically for inductive predicates, why not for functions? Or I misunderstood something?

Comment: Yes, you can do it that way. I don't know why the function package does not do it. But it's also somewhat uncommon to give names to the individual cases of function clauses. I for one cannot recall having seen that before.